# Updating UITableViewCell's objects values - Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, webclient

So I have written a downloader in iOS with Xamarin that uses 'WebClient' to download files and etc... But here is my problem; As the user adds a new file to be downloaded, it'll be added to a UITableView with a custom cell, with information like, it's name, size, and percentage. But I wanna know as download progress changes, how can I change the percentage in the file's specific cell? Well, here is the code:

First of all, I've made a class for my downloads named 'download' to get the file name, file size, and percentage:

```
using System;

namespace iDownloader
{
    internal class download
    {
        public string FileName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Uri uri
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string FileSize
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public double percentage
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Then here I've got my tableview's source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace iDownloader
{
    internal class downloadsTVS : UITableViewSource
    {
        private List<download> downloadFile;

        public downloadsTVS(List<download> downloadFile)
        {
            this.downloadFile = downloadFile;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = (DownloadCell) tableView.DequeueReusableCell("Cell", indexPath);

            var currentDownload = downloadFile[indexPath.Row];

            cell.updateCell(currentDownload);

            return cell;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return downloadFile.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Then here I've got my tableviewcell's class:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace iDownloader
{
    public partial class DownloadCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        public DownloadCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        internal void updateCell(download currentDownload)
        {
            FileNameLabel.Text = currentDownload.FileName;
            FileSizeLabel.Text = currentDownload.FileSize.ToString();
            lblPercentage.Text = currentDownload.percentage.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Then here's the code in the view controller (I've deleted unnecessary parts):
Here in the class part I've made a list of download(With file details if you remember) in order to fill my tablview. And also, I've got my webclient.

```
List<download> downloadFile = new List<download>
        {

        };
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
```

Then here is the main part:

```
private async void DownloadAsync(Uri uri, string fileName)
        {
            downloadsint++;
            TabBarItem.BadgeValue = downloadsint.ToString();
            var fileNameandPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), fileName);
            //UITableView cell adding
            download download = new download();
            download.FileName = fileName;
            webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.OpenRead(uri.ToString());
            Int64 totalbytes = System.Convert.ToInt64(webClient.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]) / 1000000;
            download.FileSize = totalbytes.ToString() + " MB";
            downloadFile.Add(download);
            tableview.Source = new downloadsTVS(downloadFile);
            tableview.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
            tableview.EstimatedRowHeight = 70f;
            tableview.ReloadData();
            //UITableView cell adding
            webClient = new WebClient();
            await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, fileName);
            btnPause.Enabled = true;
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged(fileName);
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted(fileName);
        }
public DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged(string filename)
        {
            Action<object, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> action = (sender, e) =>
            {
                double received = e.BytesReceived;
                double total = e.TotalBytesToReceive;
                double percentage = received / total * 100;
                download download = downloadFile.Find((download obj) => obj.FileName == filename);
                downloadFile.Remove(download);
                download.percentage = percentage;
                downloadFile.Add(download);
                tableview.Source = new downloadsTVS(downloadFile);
            };
            return new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(action);
        }

        public AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadFileCompleted(string filename)
        {
            Action<object, AsyncCompletedEventArgs> action = (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error.Message == "Request Aborted")
                {
                    var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Download(s) has been cancelled.", null, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Okay", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));
                    alert.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray;
                    alert.View.TintColor = UIColor.White;
                    PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
                }

                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    var alert = UIAlertController.Create("The operation has faced a problem.", null, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Okay", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));
                    alert.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray;
                    alert.View.TintColor = UIColor.White;
                    PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
                }

                if (e.Cancelled)
                {
                    var alert = UIAlertController.Create("The operation has been cancelled", null, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Okay", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));
                    alert.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray;
                    alert.View.TintColor = UIColor.White;
                    PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
                }

                else
                {
                    downloadsint--;
                    TabBarItem.BadgeValue = downloadsint.ToString();
                    //Show finished downloades notification
                    var alert = UIAlertController.Create("File has been downloaded:", "'" + filename + "' has been downloaded!", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Okay", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));
                    PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
                    //Show finished downloades notification

                    if (downloadsint == 0)
                    {
                        TabBarItem.BadgeValue = null;
                        btnPause.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
                download file = new download()
                {
                    FileName = filename
                };

            };
            return new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(action);
        }
```

So now here the problem comes up:
I've tried to pass the filename to 'DownloadProgressChanged' with 'Lambada' but it didn't work to find the file and change it's percentage and add it to "downloadFile" (*Pay attention that I've got multiple files being downloaded so I want their percentage to get updated as well.) Then finally in 'DownloadFileCompeleted' I also tried to do the same thing with 'Lambada' and find where the filename is equaled to the downloaded file and to delete the cell after the download has been finished.

So in conclusion, I need the following issues to be solved:
1- Change the percentage of downloading files (There are multiple files being downloaded.)
2- To delete the cell of the file after it's being downloaded.

Thanks guys!!! I'll be thankful to see you help.

Answer (score 0):

The code for refreshing UI(update DownloadProgress and delete cell) should be in the Main Thread.So you have better invoke it on Main Thread.
`InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        //update tableviewcell 
   });`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. So, I'm a little bit confused right now; You mean that I should put my codes inside "InvokeOnMainThread()" and write the codes. Actually, I now don't know how to update and delete the file's specific cell. If your answer is related, would you please clarify it please. Thanks for your help.

Comment: use the method   tableview.ReloadRows (NSIndexPath[] atIndexPaths, UITableViewRowAnimation withRowAnimation);

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that after adding a file it automatically adds a new row to tableview, so, I don’t know how to get that. Apart from that, saving the index with the file info can cause problems as other rows might get deleted and the index gets changed.

Comment: If you add a new row at the end of tableview,use the method NumberOfRowsInSection (nint section) to get the current number of rows